# build rails jbuilder json parameters using variable names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I'm trying to building some json output from rails using jbuilder. i have something like:

```
  json.links do | i |
    i.array!( @links ) do | j, link |
      j.source link['source']
      j.target link['target']
      j.stats do | s |
        [ 'item1', 'item2' ].each { |item|
          s.item statistics_path( :source => link['source'], :metric => item )
        }
      end
    end
  end
```

of course, this results in something like:

```
  {
    links: [
      source: "a",
      target: "b",
      stats: {
        item: 'url for item2'
      }
    ]
  }
```

when i actually want something like:

```
  {
    links: [
      source: "a",
      target: "b",
      stats: {
        item1: 'url for item1',
        item2: 'url for item2'
      }
    ]
  }
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

`json.set!(:item1, "stuff")`

In your case:

```
  json.links do | i |
    i.array!( @links ) do | j, link |
      j.source link['source']
      j.target link['target']
      j.stats do | s |
        [ 'item1', 'item2' ].each { |item|
          s.set!(item, statistics_path( :source => link['source'], :metric => item ))
        }
      end
    end
  end
```